# How to read barcode in windows phone 8.1RT

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, barcode

Can any body please tell me how to read Bar code in Windows Phone 8.1 using c#.

Answer (score 0):

There are many barcode scanning library. Two of them are:

[1] Zebra Crossing. You can download source code from http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/ for c#.net.

[2] Another one is from Manatte Works from https://manateeworks.com/

Comment: pre-requisites in Zxing.Net

Visual Studio 2010/2012
Silverlight 4 SDK (if SL4 binaries should be built)
Silverlight 5 SDK (if SL5 binaries should be built)
Windows Phone 7.0/7.1/8.0 SDK (if WP7/WP8 binaries should be built)
Unity 3D 3.5 (if Unity sample should be built)
nUnit 2.5.10 (if test should be built)
a private key for signing the assemblies or the signing has to be disabled  .  Does it work for Windows phone 8.1 RT?